# java.io.EOFException: null at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, activemq-classic

I am getting  the following error sometimes in the tomcat logs which is stopping my java process from generating file (More information on what my code does is explained below the following error message). I am not sure why this happens. When this happened, I saw in the ActiveMQ web console that there was one message pending. So, in order to fix this, I had to stop the tomcat and restart it again- which basically redeployed my java process WAR file and then that message got consumed and file got generated.This happens quite frequently. Is there something in the code (especially inside `sendMessage` method in the `RequestDaoImpl.java` file where file generation logic is written) below that doesn't look good? Please advise. Thanks !

```
 java.io.EOFException: null
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
            at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
    
    2020-07-07 09:24:14.406  WARN 3138 --- [0.1:61616@52927] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Transport (tcp://localhost:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: {}
    
    java.io.EOFException: null
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
            at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
    
    2020-07-07 09:24:14.406  WARN 3138 --- [0.1:61616@52929] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Transport (tcp://localhost:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: {}
    
    java.io.EOFException: null
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
            at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) ~[activemq-client-5.15.8.jar:5.15.8]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
    
    2020-07-07 09:24:14.407  WARN 3138 --- [0.1:61616@52932] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Transport (tcp://localhost:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: {}
```

The following is the code of my Java process deployed in Tomcat which is listening to ActiveMQ continuously and as soon as it sees COMPLETE, it sends out an email to the user after generating a file.

```
 @Component
  public class DownloadConsumer {
    
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    
    // one instance, reuse
    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    
            
    
    // Working Code with JMS 2.0
    @JmsListener(destination = "MessageProducerJMSV1")
        public void processBrokerQueues(String message) throws DaoException {
            
        
         try {
            
            RequestDao requestDao = (RequestDao) context.getBean("requestDao");
            
            String receivedStatus = requestDao.getRequestStatus(message);
            
            
             
            //Retrieve Username from the message to include in an email
             String[] parts = message.split("#");
             String userName = parts[1].trim();
             
            //Retrieve personnelID from the message to include in the webservice calls
            
             String personnelID = parts[3].trim();
            
            
            
            
            //Before sending this message, do the check for COMPLETE or ERROR etc
            if(receivedStatus.equals("COMPLETE")) {
                
                
                
                String latestUUID = requestDao.getUUID();
                
                logger.info("Received UUID in Controller is as follows! ");
                logger.info(latestUUID);
                
                requestDao.sendMessage(message,latestUUID);
                logger.info("Received status is COMPLETE! ");
                logger.info("Sending email to the user! ");
                String emailMessage = "Dear "+userName+",<p>Your files are ready. </p><p> Thanks,<br/> Jack/p>";
                String recipientEmail = userName+"@organization.com";
                
                
                
                
                /*****************************************************\
                // START: EMAIL Related Code
                
                 *******************************************************/
                
                MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
                 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
                 helper.setFrom("ABCResearch@organization.com");
                 helper.setTo(recipientEmail);
                 helper.setSubject("Requested Files !");
                 helper.setText(emailMessage,true);
                 
                 javaMailSender.send(msg);
                 
                
                    
                                
            }
            else {
                
                
                // Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();
                
                Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                
                // Destination represents here our queue 'MessageProducerJMSV1' on the  JMS server
                Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
                
                
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                
                //Sending message to the queue
                TextMessage toSendMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
                
                long delay = 300 * 1000;
                
                toSendMessage.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay);
                
                producer.send(toSendMessage);
                
                
                
                
            }
            
            }
            catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();   
                
            }
            
         }
   // URL of the JMS server. DEFAULT_BROKER_URL will just mean that JMS server is on localhost
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "MessageProducerJMSV1"; //Queue Name
    // default broker URL is : tcp://localhost:61616"
    
    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadConsumer.class);
    
    

}
```

My RequestDao interface looks like the following:

```
public interface RequestDao {
    
    public void sendMessage(String msg,String uuid) throws DaoException;
    public String getRequestStatus(String msg)throws DaoException;
    public String getUUID() throws DaoException;

}
```

And RequestDaoImpl.java looks like the following:

```
public class RequestDaoImpl implements RequestDao {
    
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
    {       
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);                                    
    }
    
    //Method to get latest UUID once the status is COMPLETE
    @Override
    public String getUUID() throws DaoException {
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String uuid = null;
        
         try {
               ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
               conn = ds.getConnection();   
               pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(getUUIDSQL);
               rs = pstmt.executeQuery();   
               logger.info("The UUID received is as follows:");
               if(rs.next()) {
                    uuid = rs.getString("UUID");
                    logger.info(uuid);
                }else {
                    logger.info("Cannot Retrieve UUID");
                }
                                
         }
         catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                if (rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmt != null) { try { pstmt.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }}
                
            }   
        
        return uuid;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getRequestStatus(String msg) throws DaoException {
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String requestStatus = null;
        
         try {
               
                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();  
                
                
                 String[] parts =   msg.split("#");
                 String requestID = parts[0].trim();
                 String userName =  parts[1].trim();
                 String applicationName = parts[2].trim();
                 
                
                
                /*===========================================================================*/
                /*    Code to get the request status from the Request Log table              */ 
                /*===========================================================================*/
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(getRequestLogSQL);
                pstmt.setString(1,userName);
                pstmt.setString(2,applicationName);
                pstmt.setString(3, requestID);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
                
                logger.info("The status received is as follows:");
                
            
                if(rs.next()) {
                    
                    requestStatus = rs.getString("REQUEST_STATUS");
                    logger.info(requestStatus);
                    
                }else {
                    logger.info("Cannot Retrieve REQUEST_STATUS for user "+userName);
                }
                                
         }
         catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                if (rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmt != null) { try { pstmt.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }}
                
            }   
        
        return requestStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String msg, String uuid) throws DaoException {
        
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtDept3 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtDept1 = null; 
        PreparedStatement pstmtDept2 = null; 
        
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rsDemo = null;
        ResultSet rsFacts = null;
        ResultSet rsEncounters = null;
        
        
        logger.info("Getting message from ActiveMQ: "+msg+" and UUID :- "+uuid+" in daoImpl");
        
         String[] parts = msg.split("#");
         String requestID = parts[0].trim();
         String userName = parts[1].trim();
         String applicationName = parts[2].trim();
         String personnelID = parts[3].trim();
        
        logger.info("Request ID "+requestID);
        logger.info("User Name "+userName);
        logger.info("Application Name "+applicationName);
        logger.info("Personnel ID "+personnelID);
        
        
        
         try {
               
                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();  
                            
                pstmtDept3 = conn.prepareStatement(getPersonDemographics);
                pstmtDept3.setString(1, requestID);
                rsDemo = pstmtDept3.executeQuery();
                
                pstmtDept1 = conn.prepareStatement(getPersonFacts);
                pstmtDept1.setString(1, requestID);
                rsFacts = pstmtDept1.executeQuery();
                
                pstmtDept2 = conn.prepareStatement(getPersonEncounters);
                pstmtDept2.setString(1, requestID);
                rsEncounters = pstmtDept2.executeQuery();
                        
                        
                 Path dir = Paths.get("/mnt/nfs/Data/dev/downloader/person_data_downloader", userName);
                 
                 Files.createDirectories(dir);
                 
                 
                 OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("mnt_nfs_Data_dev_downloader_person_data_downloader_"+ userName +"_"+ uuid +".zip"));
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
                                     
                Path file = dir.resolve("department1_person_downloader_" + uuid + ".csv");
                 Path filefacts = dir.resolve("department2_person_downloader_" + uuid + ".csv");
                 Path fileEncounters = dir.resolve("department3_person_downloader_" + uuid + ".csv");
                 
                 
                 
                 Map<String,ResultSet> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                 dataMap.put(file.getFileName().toString(),rsDemo);
                 dataMap.put(filefacts.getFileName().toString(),rsFacts);
                 dataMap.put(fileEncounters.getFileName().toString(),rsEncounters);

                 for (Map.Entry<String,ResultSet> e : dataMap.entrySet()){
                   zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(e.getKey()));
                   CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                   writer.writeAll(e.getValue(), true);
                   writer.flush();
                   zos.closeEntry();
                      
                 }
                 zos.close();
                             
                
                }
            catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                if (rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmt != null) { try { pstmt.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmtDept3 != null) { try { pstmtDept3.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe1) { sqe1.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmtDept1 != null) { try { pstmtDept1.close(); } catch(SQLException sqefacts) { sqefacts.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmtDept2 != null) { try { pstmtDept2.close(); } catch(SQLException sqeencounters) { sqeencounters.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (rsDemo != null) { try { rsDemo.close(); } catch (SQLException ed) { ed.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (rsFacts != null) { try { rsFacts.close(); } catch (SQLException efacts) { efacts.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (rsEncounters != null) { try { rsEncounters.close(); } catch (SQLException eEncounters) { eEncounters.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }}
                
            }   
        
        
        
    }
    
    

    private String getRequestLogSQL =  Utilities.getFileSQL("sql"+
            File.separator+"getRequestLog.sql", logger);
    
    private String getPersonDemographics =  Utilities.getFileSQL("sql"+
            File.separator+"getPersonDemographics.sql", logger);
    
    private String getPersonFacts =  Utilities.getFileSQL("sql"+
            File.separator+"getPersonFacts.sql", logger);
    
    private String getPersonEncounters =  Utilities.getFileSQL("sql"+
            File.separator+"getPersonEncounters.sql", logger);
    
    private String getUUIDSQL =  Utilities.getFileSQL("sql"+
            File.separator+"getUUID.sql", logger);
    
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  
    
    long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestDaoImpl.class);

    

    

}
```

In application.properties file, I have the following defined:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=failover://tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

**Edited to add more clarifications on how my stuff is working:**

I have 2 springboot apps deployed on tomcat on RHEL `server 1` & I have one activemq installed on RHEL `server 1`.

`app1` sends out message to activemq and `app2` consumes the message from activemq. `app2` seems to be having issue of connection over `tcp://localhost:61616` sometimes.

So if I decide to have second URI for the fallback broker and if the broker is located on another server (RHEL Server 2), based on my setup of 2 spring boots explained above, having a fall back broker on another server might not work.

In this scenario, what would be best strategy to follow?

Note:
The code in this post is for springboot app2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the client has lost its connection to the remote broker instance.  There are numerous reasons this can happen such as a load balancer in between or some strict firewall rules or just a general network failure of some sort.  The client can be configured to use the [failover](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) transport to automatically reconnect to the broker when it loses its connection.

Comment: Thanks Tim. 1) So in order to configure my client,do I need to put additional line (like this - `failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100` in my `application.properties`?  May be something like this : 

` spring.activemq.broker-url=failover://tcp://localhost:61616 spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100`

Comment: 2) Also, I wonder, what could be my second URL if the first one fails. For example, in the documentation, they have mentioned `failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://remotehost:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100` so if `tcp://localhost:61616` fails, it would try to reconnect using `tcp://remotehost:61616`. But since my broker is installed locally on same server, I wonder what could be my other URLs?

Comment: The options are documented and the topology depends upon your use case and isn't something that can be answered without understanding it and deciding on your requirements for availability.

Comment: Hmm, I confused as to what would be second URL in case first one fails. If you could explain with an example (in case you have done something like this before) that would be great. I am wondering if they are referring `remotehost` `tcp://remotehost:61616`  as ActiveMQ installed on some other RHEL server?

Comment: The second URI would be the address of a networked broker or the fallback broker in a primary / backup broker pair.  See https://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post to add more info about how my setup is working. Could you tell me if having a fall back URL in my scenario would make sense?